# Populating selection list from a table and inserting value into another table error

Tags: php, html, css, for-loop, mysqli

I got stuck somehow, may be very silly but cant work out quietly.
Lets say, I have 2 tables -
location (lid, company, location) 
printer (pid, lid, model, price)
in my index page I have a form to add a new printer. Here all will be text input field, but location are selected from a dropdown box. In the dropdown list, company and location both will be displayed to be selected and when one of them selected that locations id will be be taken as value and need to be inserted into printer table to be linked in to the location table for later use.
Everything is working, two columns value are displayed together to be selected but its id value aint get inserted into printer table even after selection. Could you tell me what to do?

Index.php page:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
?>

<?php include './connect.php'; ?>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Printer Page</title>

</head>

<body>
<?php

if($_POST['addprintbtn']){
$pserial = $_POST['pserial'];
$pmodel = $_POST['pmodel'];
$plocation = $_POST['plocation'];
$pprice = $_POST['pprice'];

$sql2 = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO printer(pid, model, lid, price) VALUES($pserial, $pmodel, $plocation, $pprice)");

  if($sql2 == false){
    echo "<p style='color:red'>Something is wrong! Please try again!</p> ";
  }
  else
    echo "<p style='color:green'>Printer added successfully!</p>";

}

echo "<form action='./index.php' method='post' class='form'>
<h3>Add a New Printer</h3>
<label>Printer ID/Serial </label>
<input type='text' name='pserial' required /><br/><br/>
<label>Printer Model </label>
<input type='text' name='pmodel' required /><br/><br/>
<label>Printer Price </label>
<input type='number' name='pprice' required /> BDT<br/><br/>
<label>Location </label>
<select name='plocation'>";
$sql= mysqli_query($connect, "select * from location");
foreach ($sql as $row) {
    $loc1=$row['lid'];
    $loc2 = $row['company'];
    $loc3 = $row['location'];
    echo "<option value=\"$loc1\">$loc2, $loc3</option>";
}
echo "<input style='background-color:#557755; color:#ffffff; font-weight:bold; font-size:11px;' name='addprintbtn' type='submit' value='Add Printer'>
</form>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

My database connection page connect.php

```
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");

if(mysqli_connect_errno($connect))
{
        echo 'Failed to connect';
}

?>
```

However,  when i submit the form, it doesnt insert the data and shows error.
Any help will be appreciated! Thanks again!

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Epodax Hi, there's no error. after i submit, it just doesn't insert the form data in the database as expected. However i tried to echo the data that are supposed to be inserted just before the mysqli query and it echoed the data just fine. so i guess after submission it gets the data but cannot insert into the database!

Answer (score 0):

Your `insert` query is incorrect. Change below statement

```
$sql2 = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO printer(pid, model, lid, price) VALUES($pserial, $pmodel, $plocation, $pprice)");
```

to

```
$sql2 = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO printer (pid, model, lid, price) VALUES ('".$pserial."', '".$pmodel."', '".$plocation."', '".$pprice."')");
```

Comment: sorry i edited your post mistakenly instead of mine. however the thing is that was typing error. I have actually wrote the code in the way you corrected but its still the same. Not working! any suggestion?

Comment: @MonirusSalamShuvo I suggest you to update your question first.

Comment: I have updated my query and still no luck. Any other suggestion?

Comment: @MonirusSalamShuvo : Try remove action='./index.php' from form tag

Comment: Yes. Its always showing the same red message "something is wrong" which i put there if the insert query fails! and i also tried a echo there and it seems working fine! So i guess after submitting, variable got the vaue but cannot insert it into the table for some reason!

Comment: @MonirusSalamShuvo I tried your full code with my database details and it worked fine. Can you check error logs on server?

Comment: could you send me the codes and exported sql file in a zip file? so i can compare..
mail: monirussalam@gmail.com